# Detecting egde on square wave

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, one for `time` and other for `amplitude`.

```py
time   = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]  # (seconds for example) the step isn't fixed
ampli  = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0]  # ugly space to facilitate the reading
```

I want to know when there's a change from '0' to '1' or vice-versa, but I only care if the event happens after `verify_time = X`. So, if `verify_time = 12.5` it would return `time[8] = 13` and `time[10] = 16`.

What I have so far is:

```py
time   = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]  # (seconds for example) the step isn't fixed
ampli  = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0]  # ugly spacing to facilitate the reading
verify_time = 12.5


start_end = []

for i, (t, a) in enumerate(zip(time, ampli)):
    if t >= verify_time:  # should check the values from here
        if ampli[i-1] and (a != ampli[i-1]):  # there's a change from 0 to 1 or vice-versa
            start_end.append(i)

print(f"Start: {time[start_end[0]]}s")
print(f"End: {time[start_end[1]]}s")
```

This will print:

```py
Start: 13s
End: 17s
```

Question 1) Shouldn't it print `End: 16s`? I'm kind of lost with this logic because the number of '1's is three (3).

Question 2) Is there another way to have the same results without using this `for if if`? I find it awkward, in Matlab I would use the `diff()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind using `numpy`, it is easiest, also faster in larger lists, to find edges by calculating differences, unless your waves are taking gigabytes that goes out of memory

```
import numpy as np
verify_time  = 12.5
time   = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20])
ampli  = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0])
ind = time>verify_time 
time = time[ind]
ampli = ampli[ind]
d_ampli = np.diff(ampli)
starts = np.where(d_ampli>0)[0]
ends = np.where(d_ampli<0)[0]-1
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to change the `diff` properly, it should be `d_ampli = np.diff(ampli, prepend=ampli[0]`

**UPDATE**
As you noted, the original answer returns an empty start. The reason is that after filtering the `ampli` starts with `[1, 1, ...]` so there is no edge. A philosophical question arises here, does the edge really starts before 12.5 or after it? We don't know, and I'm kinda sure you won't care. What you want here is a backward differencing scheme that numpy does not allow, so we just trick it by shifting everything forward one index as:

```
import numpy as np
verify_time  = 12.5
time   = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20])
ampli  = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0])
d_ampli = np.r_[[0], np.diff(ampli)]
starts = np.where(d_ampli>0)[0]
ends = np.where(d_ampli<0)[0]-1
start = start[time[start]>verify_time]
ends = ends[time[ends]>verify_time]
start, ends
(array([8], dtype=int64), array([10], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: I'm trying with numpy.diff(ampli) but I still don't know how to use the verify_time yet in this function. I mean, how to check only after verify_time.

Comment: Oh, you did use diff(). Nice. Thank you. Just another question. If I want to apply an amplitude threshold I would just do `d_ampli = np.diff(ampli) > threshold`?

Comment: @Richard the `ind = time>verify_time` takes care of the time, and for threshold, you are correct, just replace it with 0.

Comment: It returns [] for starts. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Richard when you set the threshold? Can you update the question with more details?

Comment: No, just running your code. I guess it's because of `ind = time>verify_time` but I still don't know how to solve yet. Diff don't get the 0 before the first one after `ind = time>verify_time`.

Comment: The reason is that when the filtering is applied first, the start of the `ampli` is 1 and the next element is also 1, so it does not qualify as an edge. To fix this, you can do the filtering after finding edges. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It prints `17s` because you take note of the first value after the change, which is `17` for the first `0` after the end of the square wave.

I've simplified the logic into a list comprehension, so you it should make more sense:

```
assert len(time) == len(ampli)
start_end = [i for i in range(len(time)) if time[i] >= verify_time and ampli[i-1] is not None and (ampli[i] != ampli[i-1])]

print(f"Start: {time[start_end[0]]}s")
print(f"End: {time[start_end[1]]}s")
```

Also, you had an issue, where `if ampli[i-1]` was also `False` when it was `0`. Fixed that too. It would be most accurate, if you took the average of `time[start_end[0]]` and `time[start_end[0]-1]`, as all you know based on your resolution, that the transition occurred somewhere between the two samples.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to implement using numpy's diff() to mimic the function I have in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the below solution to have a straightforward algorithm. In summary, it goes as follows:

1. Convert lists to NumPy arrays
2. Find closest value in time array to `verify_time`, cut off all indexes that occur beforehand.
3. NumPys' "diff" method is great for finding rising and falling edges. Once those edges are found, we can use NumPys' "where" method to look up the indexes and then return the time found at the same indexes in the time array.

### Coding Environment

- Python 3.6 (Minimum Requirement for the print statements)
- NumPy 1.15.2 (Older versions are probably fine)

```
import numpy as np

# inputs
time   = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20]  # (seconds for example) the step isn't fixed
ampli  = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0]  # ugly spacing to facilitate the reading
verify_time = 12.5

# ------------------------------------------
# Solution

# Step 1) Convert lists to Numpy Arrays
npTime = np.array(time)
npAmplitude = np.array(ampli) # Amplitude

# Step 2) Find closest Value in time array to 'verify_time'.  
# Strategy: 
# i) Subtact 'verify_time' from each value in array. (Produces an array of Diffs)
# ii) The Diff that is nearest to zero, or better yet is zero is the best match for 'verify_time'
# iii) Get the array index of the Diff selected in step ii

# Step i
npDiffs = np.abs(npTime - float(verify_time))

# Step ii
smallest_value = np.amin(npDiffs)

# Step iii (Use numpy.where to lookup array index) 
first_index_we_care_about = (np.where(npDiffs == smallest_value)[0])[0]
first_index_we_care_about = first_index_we_care_about - 1 # Below edge detection requires previous index

# Remove the beginning parts of the arrays that the question doesn't care about
npTime = npTime[first_index_we_care_about:len(npTime)]
npAmplitude = npAmplitude[first_index_we_care_about:len(npAmplitude)]

# Step 3) Edge Detection: Find the rising and falling edges

# Generates a 1 when rising edge is found, -1 for falling edges, 0s for no change
npEdges = np.diff(npAmplitude)

# For Reference
# Here you can see that numpy diff placed a 1 before all rising edges, and a -1 before falling
# ampli     [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0, 0, 0]
# npEdges   [ 0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  0, 0]

# Get array indexes where a 1 is found (I.e. A Rising Edge)
npRising_edge_indexes = np.where(npEdges == 1)[0]

# Get array indexes where a -1 is found (I.e. A Falling Edge)
npFalling_edge_indexes = np.where(npEdges == -1)[0]

# Print times that edges are found after 'verify_time'
# Note: Adjust edge detection index by '+1' to answer question correctly (yes this is consistent)
print(f'Start: {npTime[npRising_edge_indexes[0]+1]}s')
print(f'End: {npTime[npFalling_edge_indexes[0]+1]}s')
```

### Output

```
Start: 13s
End: 17s
```